# CanCan Rails How to Limit Users From Reading Data They Didn't Create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, authorization, cancan, cancancan

I'm using CanCan 1.6.1 in a Rails 3.2 application. I use `authorize_resource` in my controllers to limit what users can `:read, :create, :update: and :delete`.

In my `V2Posts controller`, the `authorize_resource` call isn't working for my `:show` action.

**In my abilities file, I'm trying to limit the user to only read their own posts. There's no error, but unfortunately, they're able to view other users posts.**

```
class V2PostsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'panel_layout', only: :show
  before_filter :redirect_if_existing, only: [:new, :create]

  authorize_resource

  def show
    @v2_post = V2Post.find(params[:id], include: :user_updates)
    @organization = @v2_post.organization

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  @user = nil

  def initialize(user)
    alias_action :taco,
                 :sandwich,
                 to: :read

    @user = user

    if user.is_in_role?(:admin)
      can :manage, :all
    else
      default_rules

      user.roles_list.each do |role|
        meth = :"#{role}_rules"
        send(meth) if respond_to? meth
      end
    end
  end

  def default_rules
    cannot [:read, :create, :update, :destroy], :all
    ...
  end

  def pro_user_rules
    can :read, V2Post, proid: @user.id
  end
...
end
```

models/v2_post.rb:

```
class V2Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :proid, :user_updates_attributes, :organization

  belongs_to :user,  :foreign_key => "proid"
  has_many :user_updates, as: :pro_post, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_updates

end
```

`load_and_authorize_resource` works for keeping the users from viewing other users' posts. But, it loads the resource for me and also adds additional database calls to other actions. Shouldn't `authorize_resource` work for my case? I've explicitly defined @v2_posts in the show action (loading the resource myself). Why isn't it getting passed to the `authorize_resource` call?

- I want to avoid requiring extra calls to the database
- I don't want to automatically load the resource for custom actions
- I want to authorize every CRUD action.

Given that, which of `load_and_authorize_resource` and `authorize_resource` works better, and what are the benefits/drawbacks of each? I've read the documentation, I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `authorize_resource` is being run as a before filter, and the instance isn't being set until inside your action--after `authorize_resource` is called. When the instance is nil, the `authorize_resource` method defaults to authorizing the class `V2Report`. Authorizing the class ignores the attribute conditions (e.g. can :read V2Report, user_id: @v2_post.user_id).

You can use `load_and_authorize` resource, and have CanCan set the instance variable in your controller before each action. For actions that load a resource in a more complicated way, like your `V2Post.find(params[:id], include: :user_updates)`, you can create a custom `prepend_before_filter` method that loads the resource for certain actions. As long as that's prepended, that loaded instance will be passed to the `authorize_resource` method. The `load_and_authorize_resource` will not make an additional call to the database if the instance is already loaded.

```
class V2PostsController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_filter :custom_load_resource, only: [:show, :edit]
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    render @v2_post
  end

  private

  def custom_load_resource
    @v2_post = V2Post.find(params[:id], include: :user_updates)
  end

end
```

You can also forget the `load_resource` altogether, and use your own before_filter 100% of the time. Or, you can ditch the filters and call `authorize!` from within the actions. In my recent experience, the approach detailed above works nicely for RESTful controllers.